# A simple example for the application of the Hartree-Fock method?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-chemistry

I'm currently reading a book about electronic structure, and I'm really interested in Hartree-Fock method. But I can only have an empirical understanding from the book. So I would like to ask for one or perhaps two simple, basic mathematical examples that I can work with to gain a better understanding of the method.

Comment: This post (v4) seems like a list question.

Comment: @Qmechanic its a good question and I'd enjoy reading an answer and trying out the problem myself! Hopefully it's been sufficiently "de-listed" (de-listicized?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest that you try to write a small code that can perform a Hartree-Fock calculation.

1. Specify molecule and basis set.
2. Get the integrals. The integrals can be hard to calculate on your own so I would suggest to obtain those from different sources, see [Programming Project #3: The Hartree-Fock Self-Consistent Field Method](http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/wiki/doku.php?id=crawdad:programming:project3)
3. Make a diagonalization of the overlap matrix, $S$, to get the transformation matrix, $ S^{-1/2} $.
   $$ S^{-1/2}=L_s\lambda_s^{-1/2}L_s^T $$
   Here $ L_s $ is the eigenvectors of the overlap matrix, and $ \lambda_s $ is the diagonalized overlap matrix.
4. Make an initial guess for the density matrix, $D$. This can be done using the core Hamiltonian $H_{core}$ as an inital guess for the Fock matrix, $F$. The core Hamiltonian is given as the sum of the kinetic energy and electron nuclei coulomb interaction integrals. Now orthonormal Fock matrix can be constructed:
   $$ F'_0 = S^{-1/2,T}H_{\mathrm{core}}S^{-1/2} $$
   This can now be diagonalized to obtain orbtial coefficients, $C'$:
   $$ F'_0C'_0=C'_0\epsilon_0 $$
   These coefficient can be back transformed $C=S^{-1/2}C'$ and used to construct the density matrix:
   $$ D_{ij,0} = \sum_{ij}^{occ}C_{i,0}C_{j,0} $$
   The inital energy can also be found as $E_{elec,0} =  \sum_{ij}^{occ}D_{ij,0}(H_{ij,\mathrm{core}}+H_{ij,\mathrm{core}})$.
5. Build new Fock matrix.
   $$ F_{ij} = H_{ij,\mathrm{core}} + \sum_{kl}^{occ}D_{kl,0}(2(ij|kl)-(ik|jl))$$
6. Build new density matrix, in the same way as the inital density matrix was build.
   $$ F' = S^{-1/2,T}FS^{-1/2} $$
   $$ F'C'=C'\epsilon $$
   $$ D_{ij} = \sum_{ij}^{occ}C_{i}C_{j} $$
   The energy can now be found as $E_{elec} =  \sum_{ij}^{occ}D_{ij}(F_{ij}+H_{ij,\mathrm{core}})$. Return to step 5 until convergence is reached.

Comment: This is what I'd call a link-only answer, and therefore not a very good answer. If the link goes dead, this answer is useless. Can you take a little more time and actually state your answer *here in your answer*? Stackexchange answers should really be able to stand on their own. So maybe choose one (or two) from that list and explain it here. There is a [tutorial for Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Put it between single dollar signs for in-line, and between pairs of dollar signs for centered. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. And thank you very much for the link to the Mathjax tutorial.

Comment: Holy granola what a transcription, very nice. `+n!` :)